# limiting the results of group_concat()

Tags: mysql

i have simple two tables

```
     table1               table2
| id |    name    |    | id |    name    |
| 1  |    name_1  |    | 1  |    name-1  |
| 2  |    name_2  |    | 2  |    name-2  |
| 3  |    name_3  |    | 3  |    name-3  |
...................    ...................
     100 row                10000 row
```

i get the names out of these tables like this

```
select 
(
  select group_concat(name) from table1
) as t1
, 
(
  select group_concat(name) from table2
) as t2
```

but i want to limit the rows results to **50 row** only

how to do that efficiently.

the results i get are like this

```
t1: name_1, name_2, name_3 . . . , name_100
t2: name-1, name-2, name-3 . . . , name-10000
```

but what i want is to stop at number 50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), first get only **50** rows. Now, you can use this result-set for `Group_concat()`

However, note this important point from the [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet.

**50** values will most likely generate a very long string (more than 1024 characters). Your result would be truncated if you don't increase the value of `group_concat_max_len` system variable before running your query:

```
-- increasing group_concat_max_len for this session
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dt.name ORDER BY dt.id) 
FROM
( 
  SELECT id, name 
  FROM table1 
  ORDER BY id LIMIT 50
) AS dt
```

Comment: @MarkElvis Remember the default max length of GROUP_CONCAT of 1204 chars.. You can/most likely must change that with `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` before this query works correctly.

Comment: @RaymondNijland would the Derived table or setting the session of its max_len work better in this situation.

Comment: You are missing the point @MarkElvis you need to execute `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` before Madhur's query..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the tip. incorporated into the answer.